# what is wrong in this android code? Using Android studio, trying to learn anonymous class

Tags: android, debugging, onclicklistener, anonymous

I am very new to android development. trying to learn anonymous interface.
what is wrong with following code? the application has just one button. The application runs but when i click on the button, it does not do anything. i.e. here it is not writing to the log.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Main Activity", "On Create");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("Main Activity","Button Clicked");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: do like `btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

Comment: did any suggestion fix your problem? Don't forget to mark one as correct :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do one of two things...

1) Make sure do declare the correct `OnClickListener` upfront...

```
import android.view.View;

...

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("Main Activity","Button Clicked");
    }
});
```

2) OR make sure that you DONT have `import static android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;` it should be...

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

...

btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("Main Activity","Button Clicked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must correct the code and use the following:

```
btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something in response to button click
    }
});
```